# using amazon api with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado

it seems that amazon has changed their API, i get error from Python:

```
id = "..."
pas = "..."
produit = amazon.API(id, pas, "fr")
produit.item_search("playstation")
```

and i get this error:

> AWSError: AWS.MissingParameters: Your request is missing required
>   parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag.

and i've tried the example in the documentation and it's the same:

```
produit.item_search('Books', Publisher='Galileo Press')
```

> AWSError: AWS.MissingParameters: Your request is missing required
>   parameters. Required parameters include AssociateTag.

i've found this:

> Changing the example to:
>
> ```
> api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, 'de',ASSOC_TAG)
> ```

from here:
https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/issue/33/required-parameters-include-associatetag

any ideas? or the documentation should be updated?

Comment: So... you did some research and found something out, and now you're asking us something completely un-specific?

Comment: no, to just explain why is this happening, because i've doznloaded the official driver and the official documentation

Comment: by the way, found this
https://github.com/dlo/bottlenose
and this is excellent since it dont require lxml which i cant install it on linux :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They dropped support for obsolete APIs recently, and the newest version requires a valid Associate Tag.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/api-changes.html

> Associate Tag Parameter: Every request made to the API should include a valid Associate Tag. Any request that does not contain a valid Associate Tag will be rejected with an appropriate error message.

ASSOC_TAG must be your real tag (one that matches the API key).

Comment: so now there are 3 keys to generate from amazon!

Comment: now am in trouble, the Associate Tag, to get it, i must provide a lot of information about payement, and the web page, and it's only a project launched from localhost! so it's no way?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: I don't know if they provide any sandbox access. Try asking on [their forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=9).

Comment: ok, that worked, it was only a required items, so no real verification, i put facebook and it worked, and got my id, hope i'll not get banned!
thank you :)

Comment: it seems that it works just by providing a web page URL, it just using a Regular Expression to detect if the url is valid or not.
thank you :D